# Solving the automation of the addition of new markets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate the addition of new markets to the spreadsheet using VBA.

In Cell E6:J6 I have 6 countries. In E7:J7 I have their respective currency. I want the user to do the following:

1. Enter a new market into H3 and its currency into I3
2. Run the macro and the new market and currency appears in K6 and K7

This part I can work out - however, when the user enters an additional market in H3 and I3, if there is a string in K6 and K7 then it will populate L6 and L7 with the new information and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is hard without seeing a data sample, but it looks like you are arranging your data against the regular flow of data from top left to bottom right.

From your description is seems like your data looks like this:

[image]

Consider re-arranging the data in a table where the first column has the country and the second column has the currency. Select a cell in that new arrangement and click Insert ribbon > Table. Now it is dead easy to add new countries. Just click the next empty cell and start typing[image]

Comment: Although i know where you are coming from, the issue I am trying to solve is - VBA copy to cell if blank, if not blank copy to cell to the next cell to the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
'This Macro will Update Rows 6 and Rows 7 from the user input for country in Range H3 and currency in Range I3        
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Rename sheet1 to your sheet name

    LastCol1 = ws1.Cells(6, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastCol2 = ws1.Cells(7, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Cells(6, LastCol1 + 1) = ws1.Cells(3,8)
    Cells(7, LastCol2 + 1) = ws1.Cells(3,9)

End Sub
```

Comment: This should work as desired!! When the user input Country in H3 and Currency in I3, the country and currency columns should be updated with new values